# fetch the right data listening to the URL in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I use react-router-dom to navigate through my components.
When I redirect to a detail component I give an item.name at the back of the URL.

```
 const selectedBeerID = '/beerItem/' + this.props.beers.selectedBeerItem.name;
        return <Redirect to={selectedBeerID}/>;
```

so the url will be like http://localhost:3000/beerItem/newName I would like to get the last parameter "newName" in my redirect page,  so I'am able to fetch the right BeerItem from my back-end in my detail component. Can someone tell me a good way to achieve this? thanks a lot!

Comment: You cane use the location prop passed to the route component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something like that in your `Router` (and you should):

```
<Route exact path={`/beerItem/:itemName`} component={BeerItemComponent} />
```

then you can access route params inside BeerItem component by

```
componentDidMount() {
  const {match: { params: { itemName } } } = this.props
  console.log(itemName) // do something with it.
}
```

**NOTE** that *BeerItemComponent* should be wrapped with `withRoute` HOC to have access to route params or use `mapStateToProps`.

[Here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/ambiguous-matches) is useful link from React Router docs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you’re looking for URL params. From the docs of react router 4, with customizations for your case:

```
<Route path="beerItem/:newName" component={Child} />

const Child = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.newName}</h3>
  </div>
);
```

Please let me know if you need additional information.